# Combine 2 integers and store it in a ulong

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, ulong

I am having a `Dictionary<int,ulong>`, where I want to store `StudentId` and his/her registered `courses` (which is guaranteed to be 2).

Now, As you can see, instead of saving 2 courseids into a `List` of Integers, i want to store them as `ulong` as `ulong` occupy 64 bits and `int` occupy 32 bits.

So my question is, how can i combine these 2 integer ids and store them into a `ulong` variable. I've tried with some Bitwise operation and shifting but unable to figure it out.

Comment: This looks like premature optimization. *Why* you want to do it like this?

Comment: Why would even consider that, I can't even figure out how you could know where the first courseid is stopping and where the second begins

Comment: I'd suggest writing a simple wrapper class, or some other predefined type such as `KeyValuPair<,>`.

Comment: int  to binary , pad the binary, concatenate like a string.. It gave me shive down my spine but I guess it will work

Comment: @OndrejTucny The end product where I am passing these data has structured like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Packing" the data of two `int`s into 64 bits can be accomplished without `ulong`, for example like this:

```
Dictionary<int,ValueTuple<int,int>>
```

[`ValueTuple<int,int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetuple(v=vs.110).aspx) takes exactly as much space as `ulong`, but it lets you access individual `int`s through its properties.

If you must use `ulong`, here is one approach that lets you pack and unpack `int`s:

```
private static ulong Combine(int a, int b) {
    uint ua = (uint)a;
    ulong ub = (uint)b;
    return ub <<32 | ua;
}
private static void Decombine(ulong c, out int a, out int b) {
    a = (int)(c & 0xFFFFFFFFUL);
    b = (int)(c >> 32);
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/XVIqe5)

Comment: It works but in a different way. I mean what i want is if one `int` is 6 & another is `10` then i want `ulong` with binary `1010 0110` with leading `0's`. So the value of `ulong` will be `166`. Is it possible?

Comment: @HarshilDoshi This is possible only if you do not intend to support the full range of integers. Otherwise it wouldn't be possible to tell apart a situation when you store `{6, 10}` vs. `{0, 166}`.

Comment: Ok let's say I am not using full ranges of integers as I am storing IDs only which won't be in a huge amount. How can I achieve that in this case?

Comment: @HarshilDoshi If your IDs are in the range 0..N-1, inclusive, use `id1*N+id2` formula to combine them and `id2=c%N`, `id1=c/N` formula to de-combine them.

Comment: Do you mean `id1<<N | id2` ?

Comment: @HarshilDoshi `id1<<N | id2` trick works when `N` is the nearest power of two for the max `id1`, e.g. if `id1` is between 0 and 100, `N` would be 7, because the nearest power of 2 above 100 is 128. The trick with division and remainder that I described in the comment works for any `N`.